# Changing value inside foreach loop doesn't change value in the array being iterated over

Tags: php, foreach

Why does this yield this:

```
foreach( $store as $key => $value){
$value = $value.".txt.gz";
}

unset($value);

print_r ($store);

Array
(
[1] => 101Phones - Product Catalog TXT
[2] => 1-800-FLORALS - Product Catalog 1
)
```

I am trying to get 101Phones - Product Catalog TXT.txt.gz

Thoughts on whats going on?

EDIT: Alright I found the solution...my variables in my array had values I couldn't see...doing

```
$output = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $output);
echo($output);
```

Cleaned it up and made it work properly

Answer (score 40):

The doc http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php clearly states why you have a problem:

"In order to be able to directly modify array elements within the loop precede $value with &. In that case the value will be assigned by reference."

```
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
// $arr is now array(2, 4, 6, 8)
unset($value); // break the reference with the last element
?>
```

Referencing $value is only possible if the iterated array can be referenced (i.e. if it is a variable). The following code won't work:

```
<?php
/** this won't work **/
foreach (array(1, 2, 3, 4) as &$value) {
    $value = $value * 2;
}
?>
```

Comment: I am still getting this when I follow your first example: Array
(
.txt.gz => 101Phones - Product Catalog TXT
.txt.gz => 1-800-FLORALS - Product Catalog 1
) why is it assigning my key as the text I am adding to the variable?

Comment: if anyone happens to stumble into this like I did after me, this is the solution to this question most of the time. OP, consider marking this as the right answer, if you ever login again...

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
foreach( $store as $key => $value){
    $store[$key] = $value.".txt.gz";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `$value` variable in the array is temporary, it does not refer to the entry in the array.
If you want to change the original array entry, use a reference:

```
foreach ($store as $key => &$value) {
                       //  ^ reference
    $value .= '.txt.gz';
}
```

Comment: When I do that it gives me: Array
(
.txt.gz => 101Phones - Product Catalog TXT
.txt.gz => 1-800-FLORALS - Product Catalog 1
)

Comment: It should certainly not do that. Post the full code that produces that result.

Comment: I just realized it is something weird from my variables ....I created an array $stores=array("tree","boat"); and it worked...whats a good way to remove unseen characters?

Answer (score 4):

You are rewriting the value within the loop, and not the key reference in your array.

Try

```
 $store[$key] = $value.".txt.gz";
```

Answer (score 3):

pass `$value` as a reference:

```
foreach( $store as $key => &$value){
   $value = $value.".txt.gz";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$catalog = array();

foreach( $store as $key => $value){
    $catalog[] = $value.".txt.gz";
}


print_r ($catalog);
```

OR

```
foreach( $store as $key => $value){
    $store[$key] = $value.".txt.gz";
}


print_r ($store);
```

Depends on what you want to achieve

Thanks
:)

Comment: Its omitting the .txt.gz Array
(
    [1] => 101Phones - Product Catalog TXT
    [2] => 1-800-FLORALS - Product Catalog 1
)

Answer (score 2):

How about array map:

```
$func = function($value) { return $value . ".txt.gz"; };
print_r(array_map($func, $store));
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you want to do:

```
foreach( $store as $key => $value){
$store[$key] = $value.".txt.gz";
}

unset($value);

print_r ($store);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(array_container as & array_value)
```

Is the way to modify array element value inside foreach loop.