# Can't change string in php array

Tags: php

I am trying to surround strings in a php array with `<p id=para>` and `</p>` here is my code.  Nothing happens when I run it.

```
foreach($i=0;$i < count($tags); $i++){
    $tags[$i] = "<p id=para>" . $tags[$i] . "<p>";
}
```

Tags is my array of strings.

Comment: Have you forgotten to end it with "</p>" or is it just a typo? Also you are mistaking for and & foreach loops.

Comment: 1. You're mixing `foreach` and `for` syntax 2. Don't save html tags in an array!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920619/changing-value-inside-foreach-loop-doesnt-change-value-in-the-array-being-itera, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121483/php-modify-current-object-in-foreach-loop (and http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: @Rizier123 Why not store them in array until printing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this instead.

```
foreach($tags as &$tag){
    $tag = "<p id=para>" . $tag . "</p>";
}
```

The & references tag instead of copying it, which is your problem it won't change the string in the actual array.

Comment: Might be a good idea to explain why this would work, especially what the `&` sign does! ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a few issues in your code snippet.

First off: You are using a `foreach-loop`, but supplying arguments as if it was a `for-loop`.
You generate `invalid` HTML, your `id` attribute need to enclose the value in `"` or `'`, eg: `id="para"`.
You'r `<p>` tag is not closed, but instead followed by another `<p>` tag (should be a `</p>`).

You can use either a for-loop or a foreach-loop, but they work differently.
A for-loop would be written much like the one you got:

```
 for($i=0;$i < count($tags); $i++) { ...
```

While a foreach would look more like:

```
foreach($tags as &$tag) { ...
```

Notice the `&` sign before `$tag`, the `&` indicates that it is a reference to the object, that means, if you change the object inside the `foreach loop`, it will actually be changed, not just inside the `foreach` scope.

This means that you can edit the `$tag` object right away instead of accessing it from the array.
If you rather access it from the array, but still wish to use a `foreach` you can get both the index (the key) and the value by:

```
foreach($tags as $key => $value) {
   $tags[$key] = 'html' . $value . 'endhtml';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide which of the loops you intend to use. At the moment it looks like you have mistaken `for` & `foreach` loops.

---

Luckily, this may be done by both ways.

## Using `for` loop

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($tags); $i++)
{
    $tags[$i] = "<p id='para'>" . $tags[$i] . "</p>";
}
```

## Using `foreach` loop

As mentioned earlier, but without a real explanation:

```
foreach($tags as &$tag){
    $tag = "<p id='para'>" . $tag . "</p>";
}
```

Where the `&$tag` does *a reference*, not *a copy*, therefore it updates the string inside the array. The way you tried to do it, it would only change the copy of it.

And finally, one last thing - If I may recommend, start using apostrophes/quotes when specifying attributes of html tags. It is more clean, more valid and way better looking.

Answer (score -1):

**Either Use**

for($i=0;$i < count($tags); $i++){

```
$tag[] = "<p id='para'>" . $tags[$i] . "<p>";
```

}

**Or Use**

foreach($tags as $tg){

```
$tag[] = "<p id='para'>" . $tg . "</p>";
```

}