# foreach loop scope with multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, string

Can someone explain the output of this code?

Why is it "fb" instead of "100100"?

```
$items = array();
$items[] = "foo";
$items[] = "bar";

foreach($items as $item) {
    $item['points'] = 100;
}

foreach($items as $item) {
    echo $item['points']; //output: "fb"
}
```

Comment: Do you perhaps mean that the output is "foobar"?

Comment: @kittykittybangbang no, it is "fb"...weird, huh?

Comment: $item is a string，I just get  Warning [code](https://eval.in/403699).you can add print_r($items) follw the first foreach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You loop though the `$items` array, which has two elements.

First: `foo` and second: `bar`. E.g.

```
Array (
  [0] => foo
  [1] => bar
)
```

Now you access them like this:

```
echo $item['points'];
```

PHP will convert `points` which is a string into an integer, as you can see from the manual warning:

> **Warning:** *[...]* **Non-integer types are converted to integer.** *[...]*

Which in your case will be 0.

And so you access the [two values (strings) as array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr):

```
string: f o o
index:  0 1 2  //$index["points"] -> $index[0]

string: b a r
index:  0 1 2  //$index["points"] -> $index[0]
```

So you print the first character of both strings (e.g. **f**oo and **b**ar), which are:

```
fb
```

**EDIT:**

Also worth to note here is, that PHP only silently converts it with PHP <5.4 from newer version you will get a warning, as from the manual:

> As of **PHP 5.4** string offsets have to either be **integers or integer-like strings, otherwise a warning will be thrown**. Previously an offset like "foo" was **silently cast to 0**.

Which in your case with PHP >=5.4 you would get:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'points' ...

Comment: @Darren It's 04:27 AM in the morning, so I guess 1 typo is allowed :) (Thanks for the fix)

Comment: Haha I just had to ;-) 3 coffees in here !

Comment: It makes sense, I'm not sure why I didn't realise it. Foo and Bar are just string values, not arrays themselves, so trying to call $item['points'] wouldn't work. Odd why PHP would just convert points to an integer though, and not throw an exception.

Comment: @cid You're welcome. It can be really confusing if you don't know that you can access a string as an 0-based index array in PHP.

Comment: @cid updated my answer. It's also worth to note, that it only converts it silently with PHP < 5.4, in newer version you will get a warning.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question intriguing.

I had my own walk-through and here is the result.

`$items` is defined as follows.

```
$items = [
  0 => "foo",
  1 => "bar"
];
```

Then, goes into the `foreach` loop.

```
foreach($items as $item) {
    $item['points'] = 100;
}
```

At the beginning, `$item` contains a string `"foo"`. The `[]` syntax is dominantly used for associative arrays, so it tricks us that `$item` might be an array, which is not the case. A less well-known usage of the `[]` is to get/set a single character in a string via `[int]` or `{int}` expression, as @Rizier123 has noted in his answer. For example, a `"string"[0]` gives `"s"`. So, the following code

```
$item['points'] = 100;
```

is virtually similar to

```
"foo"['points'] = 100;
```

Now, a non-integer value given as a character position of a string, raises a PHP warning, and the position (here `'points'`) will be force-converted to an integer.

```
// Converting a string to integer:
echo intval('points'); // gives 0
```

As a result, the `"foo"['points']"` statement becomes `"foo"[0]`, so

```
"foo"[0] = 100;
```

Now, the assignment part. The `[]` syntax operates on a single character. The numeric `100` is first converted to a string `"100"` and then only the first character is taken out for the assignment operation(`=`). The expression is now similar to

```
"foo"[0] = "1"; // result: "1oo"
```

To make things a bit twisted, the modified value of `$item`( which is `"1oo"`) is not preserved. It's because the `$item` is not a reference. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920684/760211 for more information.

So, all the previous operations are negligible in terms of the end result. The `$items` are intact in the original state.

Now, in the last loop, we can see that the `$item['point']` statement tries to read a character out of a string, in an erroneous way.

```
foreach($items as $item) {
    echo $item['points']; //output: "fb"
}

echo "foo"[0]; // "f"
echo "boo"[0]; // "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not actually modifying the array by doing $items as $item. $item is its own variable, so it would make sense that you get the correct output when printing within that loop.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my comment. It will print out "11" as the output. Also, do you mean that $item is a temporary variable accessible only within the loop? Then why can I do this with a while loop?