# Adding field on array on PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to add a field in an array and return it, but according to `var_dump`, no changes are made to the array. The instruction in the if-block is executed and the data seems correct.

```
function addLength($toAdd, $added){
   $result = $toAdd;
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        foreach ($added as $key => $value) {
            if($key == $row['id'] ){
                $row['length'] = $value;   
            }
        } 
    }
    var_dump($result);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: It will be really helpful if you show your current results and the desirable results!

Comment: The array shold have the field 'length' added but it doesn't nothing has changed.

Comment: `foreach` creates copies of the data. If you change `$row` (the copy), the original array (`$result`) won't be affected. Try changing the foreach to use references instead: `foreach ($result as &$row)` (the added & sign).

Comment: your final $result no update and your $row will be update in this code.

Comment: if($key == $row['id'] ){
                $result['length'] = $value;   
            }
it will be effect your result

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920619/changing-value-inside-foreach-loop-doesnt-change-value-in-the-array-being-itera See Answer from Michel; Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121483/php-modify-current-object-in-foreach-loop; Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15024616/php-foreach-change-original-array-values

Answer (score 5):

When dealing with `$row` in the [`foreach` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) you aren't dealing with the same variable that is in the array, but a copy. If you want to make lasting changes you need to use a [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php#language.references.whatdo.pass).

```
function addLength($toAdd, $added){
   $result = $toAdd;
    foreach ($result as & $row) {
        foreach ($added as $key => $value) {
            if($key == $row['id'] ){
                $row['length'] = $value;   
            }
        } 
    }
    var_dump($result);
    return $result;
}
```

Please make sure to note that a reference will still exist **after** the `foreach` loop has completed. It will contain a reference to the last element of your `$result` array. To stop this you would need to manually [`unset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) the reference.

```
    function addLength($toAdd, $added){
   $result = $toAdd;
    foreach ($result as & $row) {
        foreach ($added as $key => $value) {
            if($key == $row['id'] ){
                $row['length'] = $value;   
            }
        } 
    }
    var_dump($row); // Outputs the last element of your $result array
    unset($row);
    var_dump($row); // Now undefined.

    var_dump($result);
    return $result;
}
```

Just as an FYI, you can optimise your code and get rid of the second foreach loop, it's just not necessary. This would do the same:

```
function addLength($toAdd, $added){
   $result = $toAdd;
    foreach ($result as & $row) {
        if ( array_key_exists($row['id'], $added) ) {
            $row['length'] = $added[$row['id']];
        }
    }
    var_dump($result);
    return $result;
}
```

Now rather than looping through `$added` for every item in `$toAdd` you just check to see if the data is there (by checking for the array key) and if it is, use it.

Comment: @af_inb I've updated my answer to also include some information on optimising your code. I hope this helps :).

Answer (score 2):

`foreach` copies each element of the array into a variable, so your changes have no effect. Update the original array instead:

```
function addLength($toAdd, $added){
   $result = $toAdd;
    foreach ($result as $outerKey => $row) {
        foreach ($added as $key => $value) {
            if($key == $row['id'] ){
                $result[$outerKey]['length'] = $value;   
            }
        } 
    }
    var_dump($result);
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you want to add this type change

```
function addLength($toAdd, $added){
 $result = $toAdd;
 foreach ($result as $first_key => $row) {
    foreach ($added as $key => $value) {
        if($key == $row['id'] ){
            $result[$first_key]['length'] = $value;   
        }
    } 
}
var_dump($result);
return $result;
}
```

if you do not add key value in index then you can use this code

```
 function addLength($toAdd, $added){
 $result = $toAdd;
 foreach ($result as $first_key => $row) {
    foreach ($added as $key => $value) {
        if($key == $row['id'] ){
            $result[]['length'] = $value;   
        }
    } 
}
var_dump($result);
return $result;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong, you're using the wrong key. You'd have to use `foreach ( $result as $i => $row )` then `$result[$i]['length'] = $value;`

Comment: Still wrong, `$yourkey` is for the `$added` array, not the `$result` array.

Comment: sorry it was mistake, i was busy some task so this mistake. now fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Change the line:

```
$row['length'] = $value;
```

to:

```
$result[$row]['length'] = $value;
```

If that doesn't work, you will need to change the `foreach ($result as $row)` loop to:

```
foreach ($result as $row => $data)
```

Comment: Hence the last part of my answer to change the loop... No info on input parameters makes it difficult to provide accurate answer.

Answer (score -1):

Correct me if in wrong but ($result as $row) assigns $row to a copy of an element in $result. It is not referencing the original element in $result. Try foreach($result as &$row)
If you do use a reference variable in a foreach loop remember to unset it after the loop with unset($row).